# refresh div not work - jquery command load

Tags: html, jquery, refresh

i am trying to solve a problem via jquery.
I have an .asp page that contains the following div:

```html
select case checkPreferiti(Session("userID"),rs("idProdotto"))
      case False
           %><div id=togglePreferiti"><button class="btn btn-danger my-cart-btn my-cart-b" id="SetBookmark" value="Aggiungi">Aggiungi ai preferiti</button></div><%
       case True
           %><div id=togglePreferiti"><button class="btn btn-danger my-cart-btn my-cart-b" id="SetBookmark" value="Rimuovi">Rimuovi dai preferiti</button></div><%
end select
```

Jquery call another .asp page who add/remove record in database:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#SetBookmark').on('click', function(){
            var action;
            var idProdotto = <% =request("ProdID") %>;

            if ($(this).attr("value") == 'Aggiungi') {
                action = 'add';
            } else {
                action = 'remove';
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "setPreferitiDiv.asp",
                data: { bookmark: action, prodID: idProdotto },
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){

                $("#togglePreferiti").load(window.location.href + " #togglePreferiti");
                
                }
            })
        });
   });
```

Everything works except the last command (load).
I also tried with the button instead of the div.
can you tell yourself where I'm wrong?

Comment: You load the togglePreferiti into the togglePreferiti - you need to load the content of togglePreferiti into togglePreferiti on the page - can't you just return the `<button ...>`  from the ajax?

Comment: Calling `$.ajaxSetup()` in the callback of an AJAX request seems like a mistake - it's too late to have any effect on the first AJAX request made, unless that's intentional? Seems odd either way

Comment: Yes Rory, is a mistake. Now delete the row.

Comment: mplungjan, sintax is  $("#myDiv").load(location + " #MyDiv").
I don't know jquery well, but online is the only sintax found.